# Dividing by two integers does not return expected result

Tags: c#

I'm currently writing a program that requires a preview of a live display, but the preview, of course, is scaled down. However, when I scale the `PictureBox` down, the size is incorrect. For the scale to be correct the width and height need to be at a 4:3 ratio. Here's the code:

```
private void FindOptimalRes(PictureBox picBox)
{
    double h = Height / 4;
    double ratio = 4 / 3;
    picBox.Size = new Size((int)(h * ratio), (int)h);
}
```

In testing, `Height` (the height of the form) is 400, so, the width of the new size should be 133. But it always gets resized to 100×100! Why?

Comment: You should make sure whether YOU have the wrong before say that C# has a math wrong

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? Just because someone is ignorant about something is not a reason for downvoting his question. He even showed his code and everything.

Comment: I think, perhaps: "Try to choose a more accurate/issue-reflecting and less combative title .."

Comment: This is a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841332/why-is-the-division-result-between-two-integers-truncated Also, I've changed your title to make it easier for future visitors with a similar problem to find this post. I see minitech removed your last line - thanks @minitech!

Comment: Okay.. Thank you, Dash. I apologize for my.. noobiness? Whatever. :P Thanks, again. Lol..

Comment: So, I know this is an old post, but I just wanted to point out that, at the time of making this question, I was fairly new to C#. I know Java pretty well, but I was not aware that you had to specify that the variables were doubles for them to work in division properly. Just wanted to clear that up..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`4` and `3` are both `int`s, so it gets turned to `1`. Make them something floating-point:

```
double ratio = 4.0 / 3.0;
```

Note that you're also making the same mistake with `Height` (it doesn't matter right now, but it will - change it to `4.0`). And if this is the actual code, why divide by four to multiply by four again?

```
private void FindOptimalRes(PictureBox picBox)
{
    picBox.Size = new Size(Height / 3, Height / 4);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

C#'s math is "correct". The understanding of what is being done is .. missing :-)

The expression `4 / 3` (of type `int / int`) will evaluate to the *integer* value 1 as it is using *integer division* (both *operands* are integers). The resulting 1 is then implicitly coerced to a double value on assignment.

On the other hand `4d / 3` will "work" (and results in a *double* 1.333_) because now it is `double / int` -> `double / double (by promotion)` -> `double` using the appropriate *floating point division*.

Similarly, for `Height / 4` (assuming Height is an integer), these would work:

```
(double)Height / 4          // double / int -> double
Height / 4d                 // int / double -> double
(double)Height / (double)4  // double / double -> double
```

Happy coding!

Comment: For the record, I do know that C#'s math is correct. It's been quite a while since I've programmed in general and nearly a year since in C#, so I simply forgot that little rule. But thank you for the correct answer and for reminding me of this. :P

Answer (score 3):

You are doing integer division:

```
double ratio = 4 / 3; // evaluates to 1
```

This won't give you the value you are looking for because the decimal point is being truncated, thus evaluating to `1` instead of `1.333`. At least one of the operands needs to be a double:

```
double ratio = 4.0 / 3.0; // evaluates to 1.333
```

Same goes for `Height`. Change the `4` to `4.0`.

Comment: Thank you. You realized I was kidding about C#'s math being off and you gave me a straight (and correct) answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure division result is `double`

```
double ratio = (double) 4 / 3; // double division
```

and no need to set your input values to double.

```
var num1 = // an integer number
var num2 = // an integer number

//result is integer, because of integer/integer uses 'integer division'
double result = num1 / num2; 

//result is double , because of you forced to 'double division'
double result = (double) num1 / num2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do a decimal division and not integer division:

```
double h = Height / 4.0;
double ratio = 4 / 3.0;
```

If C# Math was off many things around the world would be off as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing integer division.

what you need to do is this :

```
private void FindOptimalRes(PictureBox picBox)
{
    double h = Height / 4D; // or Height / 4.0
    double ratio = 4D / 3D; // or 4.0 / 3.0
    picBox.Size = new Size((int)(h * ratio), (int)h); // Size is now correct [133,100]
}
```

when you do a mathematical operation with an integer literal (no decimal places) it is implicitly typed as an int.

Simply appending a capital D at the end of your literals (4D, 3D) will type them as doubles, and your math will be correct.  Alternatively you can write 4.0, 3.0