# Why Can't I Peform Basic Equation in C# Object?

Tags: c#, linq

```
ViewBag.WinLossRatio = 
    new WinLossRatioVM
    {
        Wins = ctx.Games.Where(p => p.IsWin == true).Count(),
        Total = ctx.Games.Count(),
        Percent = ctx.Games.Where(p => p.IsWin == true).Count() / ctx.Games.Count() * 100
    };
```

In the above code, I simply try to get the ratio of wins to the total number of games played.  The first two properties, Wins and Total return five and eleven, respectively.  The last property only returns as zero.  The model is simply as follows:

```
public class WinLossRatioVM
{
    public int Wins { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Percent { get; set; }
}
```

Why does Percent return zero?

Comment: there are at least thousands of questions about this.

Comment: why are you defining `Wins` and `Total` when you are not using it? Shouldn't it be `Percent = Wins / Total * 100`?

Comment: @Ben, likely they are used somewhere else. That being said, the reuse makes sense to me.

Comment: @Ben You can't use those since they haven't been defined yet.

Comment: other duplicates: 1) [Dividing by two integers does not return expected result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487577/dividing-by-two-integers-does-not-return-expected-result)  2) [What's wrong with this division?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704702/whats-wrong-with-this-division) 3) [Divide not returning the decimal value I expect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597029/divide-not-returning-the-decimal-value-i-expect)

Comment: @Selman22 And how the hell was I supposed to find that; this would have been a difficult problem to google for since it's so vague...

Comment: By the way, replace `.Where(something).Count()` by `.Count(something)` directly.

Comment: @user1477388 It ain't vague at all. Googling "C# Division returns 0" returns immediately [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288904/division-returns-zero), and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205490/why-do-these-division-equations-result-in-zero). And a bunch of [answers elsewhere](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/78281158-6479-49c9-b4ab-8c5bbcc250f1/why-does-this-seemlingly-sinple-division-always-return-0?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I guess - just didn't think I would find anything for such a vague problem - it could be returning zero for a number of reasons it seemed.

Comment: @user1477388 There's over 645k questions in the C# tag alone, you can find almost anything if you search just a little bit. By the way I just saw there's 5 other questions exactly like yours in the section named "Linked"...

Answer (score 2):

Cast the properties as decimals, float or double as you need the decimal places for the percentage calculation.

Comment: The more common solution is to cast to float, but sure decimal works too.

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler throw some sort of error in this case; how was I supposed to know it can't divide one int by another...

Comment: @user1477388, It absolutely can divide one int by another, it just truncates the fractional part! 4/2 will yield the correct answer, 5/2 will return 2 etc. No compiler error necessary.

Comment: Whats really happening is eg: (int)50/(int)100 = (int)0 * (int)100 = 0.

Comment: Well I upvoted your post.  The other folks aptly pointed out that this question has been answered time and time again - so i guess i will delete it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess its hard to define a search term for this type of problem.

Comment: Thank you!  You're the only one who gets that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Percent = ctx.Games.Where(p => p.IsWin == true).Count() / ctx.Games.Count() * 100
```

Is using integer division, you need to cast at least one argument to a float so you are using floating point division:

```
Percent = Convert.ToInt32(ctx.Games.Where(p => p.IsWin == true).Count() / (float)(ctx.Games.Count()) * 100);
```

Integer division will truncate any fractional component, leaving 0 in percentage calculations < 100%

Comment: You can't do this, Wins and Total won't do not exist in that context, VS says.

Comment: I saw your comment below, you say it is common to cast to float instead of double; is there any advantage?

Comment: @FunctionR, Not really. Float easily contains the range of an int, so you don't need the increased precision of double or decimal. Its also called "floating point division" so the use of float makes it obvious that thats what it will use.

Comment: Another reason why this won't work, because you have to convert it to int, since Percent is int, `Percent = Convert.ToInt16(ctx.Picks.Where(p => p.IsWin == true).Count() / (float)ctx.Picks.Count() * 100)`

Comment: @user1477388, another excellent catch. Just cast the result to int (no need to use Convert if you don't want to) Edited to include the cast. The more common use of percent is as a float (so you get the precision), hence my lack of cast.

Comment: Thanks, but the implicit cast won't work, it has to be done with the Convert method.

Comment: Whats the error you are getting? This seems to need some research, I swear I've done that before... Regardless, updated to your code in case I'm wrong :)

Comment: Well I upvoted your post.  The other folks aptly pointed out that this question has been answered time and time again - so i guess i will delete it.