# A mathematical Expression is always ZERO?

Tags: java

I do not why the below mathematical operation gives me `0.0`

Mathematical_expression:

```
double percentageAmongAll = ((itemClickedID+1)/(parent.getCount()));
```

Logcat_Output:

```
06-14 13:46:53.176: I/MySavedLocation(19361): parent.getCount() = 3
06-14 13:46:53.176: I/MySavedLocation(19361): itemClickedID+1 = 2
06-14 13:46:53.176: I/MySavedLocation(19361): percentageAmongAll = 0.0
```

Comment: It [gives you `0`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22341128/11683). Only later it becomes `0.0`.

Comment: @GSerg but i expect the result to be .666666

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`itemClickedID+1` and `parent.getCount()` are integer expressions. Integer division always returns integers, so `2/3` returns `0` which is then converted to `0.0`.

```
double percentageAmongAll =  ((double) itemClickedID+1)/(parent.getCount());
```

This will cast `itemClickedId` to a double, so a double division will be performed.

Comment: `(itemClickedID+1.0)/(parent.getCount())` would do it as well.  The `1.0` turns the numerator into a double and so the whole expression is calculated as a double, not an integer.

Comment: Yes, of course, there are dozens of ways to achieve it.