# Calculating Percentage Change returns 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried to find the percentage change of a `float`, however the query returns `0.00`

```
SELECT CAST(((SELECT 115301-(SELECT 114256))/(SELECT 114256))*100 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

Is there anything that I miss here? Where should I edit the SQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server, division returns zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666407/sql-server-division-returns-zero), [why does sql server return 0 for 1 / 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33517276/3484879)

Comment: Also, why `(SELECT 115301-
(SELECT 114256))`? What wrong with `SELECT (115301 - 114256)`?

Comment: Another note: `115301` isn't a `float`, it's an `int`. A `float` would use scientific notation, such as `1.15301e5`.

Comment: Thank you. actually the lines are longer. but I just simplified by showing some numbers there. I've added the cast as float in the query lines and now its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try below it will work**

```
SELECT CAST(CAST((115301-114256) AS FLOAT)/114256*100 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT CAST(((SELECT 115301.00- (SELECT 114256.00))/(SELECT 114256.00))*100 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

> Or cast numbers to float or decimal

```
SELECT CAST(((SELECT cast(115301 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) - (SELECT cast(114256 AS DECIMAL(18,2))))/(SELECT cast(114256 AS DECIMAL(18,2))))*100 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
```

Comment: This is quite clearly a duplicate of those linked above. Adding `.00` to the end of the value works for literals, but wouldn't for a column's name (`[MyColumn].00` would error), so doesn't show a solution that works regardless of the items in the expression. Also, why not fix the other problems with the query at the same time?

Comment: you should cast all columns to decimal(18,2) like this : ```SELECT CAST(((SELECT cast(115301 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) -
(SELECT cast(114256 AS DECIMAL(18,2))))/(SELECT cast(114256 AS DECIMAL(18,2))))*100 AS DECIMAL(18,2))```